# How to active the respective image on clicking on the accordion?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have three accordions on the left side and three images on the right side (It will increase in the future).
What I am doing is, on the page load first accordion is always open and the first image will display on-page. Once the user clicks the second accordion then I have to the second image or click on the third accordion then show the third image.

I tried the below code but little bit confused. I am getting the id by clicking on the accordion but now how can I activate the image?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".accordion-header").click(function() {
    $target = $(this).attr('id');
    alert($target);

  });
});
```

```css
.custom-images img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-6">
      <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
            <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        Accordion Item #1
      </button>
          </h2>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="accordion-body">
              <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing
              and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit
              overflow.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
            <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
        Accordion Item #2
      </button>
          </h2>
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="accordion-body">
              <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing
              and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit
              overflow.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
            <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
        Accordion Item #3
      </button>
          </h2>
          <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="accordion-body">
              <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing
              and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit
              overflow.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-6">
      <div class="custom-images">
        <div class=""><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff"></div>
        <div class="d-none" id><img src="https://dummyimage.com/700x400/000/fff"> </div>
        <div class="d-none"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/800x400/000/fff"> </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass id on the images so you can target it easily to show on accordion click. Here is the code https://jsfiddle.net/54kp6mqc/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-6">
      <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading1">
            <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse1">
        Accordion Item #1
      </button>
          </h2>
          <div id="collapse1" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="heading1" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="accordion-body">
              <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing
              and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit
              overflow.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading2">
            <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse2">
        Accordion Item #2
      </button>
          </h2>
          <div id="collapse2" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="heading2" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="accordion-body">
              <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing
              and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit
              overflow.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading3">
            <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse3">
        Accordion Item #3
      </button>
          </h2>
          <div id="collapse3" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="heading3" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="accordion-body">
              <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing
              and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit
              overflow.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-6">
      <div class="custom-images">
        <div class="" id="img_1"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff"></div>
        <div class="d-none" id="img_2"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/700x400/000/fff"> </div>
        <div class="d-none" id="img_3"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/800x400/000/fff"> </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".accordion-header").click(function() {
    $target = $(this).attr('id');
    $id= $target.match(/\d+/);
    $('.custom-images div').addClass('d-none');
    $('#img_'+$id).removeClass('d-none');

  });
});
```

Comment: Yes, It's working. I want to know why you used    $id= $target.match(/\d+/);

Comment: $id= $target.match(/\d+/); using this we get last number of the accordion id like 2 from the heading2 id and using this number we get image id and will display it.